# Wie erklären sich bairische Formen wie »gefreuen« oder »gestellen«?

Tags: verb, prefix, bavarian

Man stelle sich folgende Situation vor: Ein Hund hat eine Befehlskette fehlerfrei durchgezogen, zur Belohnung kriegt er seinen Stoffknochen und darf mit Herrchen Tauziehen spielen. Eine Beobachterin der Szene wendet sich zu ihrer Nachbarin und sagt über den Hund:

> Schau, jetz **gfreit** er si.

Oder mit standarddeutscher Aussprache:

> Schau, jetzt **gefreut** er sich.

---

Zweites Beispiel: Ein Bub steht auf dem Fünfmeterbrett und traut sich nicht, herunterzuspringen. Seine Freunde von unten rufen zu ihm hinauf:

> Jetz **gstoi** di neda so!

Oder mit standarddeutscher Aussprache:

> Jetzt **gestell** dich nicht so!

---

Beide Verben, *gestellen* und *gefreuen* sind meines Wissens in dieser Form nur im bairischen Sprachraum bekannt; außerhalb dessen würde man schlicht von *freuen* oder *(an)stellen* sprechen. Mich wundert, warum hier im bairischen – sowohl in der Umgangssprache wie auch im Dialekt – Verben mit einem Präfix *ge-* an ihre Stelle treten.

Wie erklärt sich die Verwendung von *gefreuen* und *gestellen* anstelle der simpleren *freuen* und *stellen?*

---

Anmerkungen: Es handelt sich bei beiden Formen zweifellos um Präsenskonstruktionen. *Gestellen* steht in klarem Gegensatz zu *stellen* – niemand würde sagen »*Gestell das Glump in die Ecke«. (Es ist allerdings vorstellbar, dass *anstellen* statt *gestellen* im Beispiel verwendet wird.) *Gefreuen* und *freuen* sind deutlich näher beieinander, ob sie völlig austauschbar sind, vermag ich im Stegreif nicht zu sagen.

Comment: Man vergleiche den *Gestellungsbefehl*, der eindeutig hochdeutsch, wenn nicht gar ur-preußisch ist. Herr Grimm kennt auch (noch) ein Verb dazu mit der Bedeutung *sich einstellen/-finden*. Das ist hier aber wohl nicht gemeint.

Comment: Es heißt eben NICHT »gefreut« sondern »gfreit«. Kein Mensch sagt »Schau, jetzt gefreut er sich« oder »Jetzt gestell dich nicht so!« Dialekte unterscheiden sich von der Standardsprache sowohl durch eine andere Grammatik als auch durch ein anderes Vokabular. Einem bairischen Dialekt mit standarddeutscher Grammatik zu Leibe rücken zu wollen, kann manchmal durchaus sinnvoll sein, oft wird es aber so sein, wie wenn man versucht Englisch oder Dänisch vom Standpunkt deutscher Grammatik aus zu untersuchen.

Comment: Wenn man das Vokabular einer Sprache mit der Grammatik einer anderen Sprache kreuzt, kommt nur unsinniges Zeug heraus, aus dem sich für keine der beiden Sprachen etwas Vernünftiges ableiten lässt.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Mir geht es nicht um die Grammatik sondern um die Wortform. Ich halte das *ge-* hier nicht für ein grammatikalisches Präfix (sonst hätte ich einen grammatikalischen Tag dazugesetzt). Was ich getan habe, ist lediglich die bairischen Laute auf ihre üblichen standarddeutschen Äquivalente zurückzuführen, um Nichtbairischsprechern einen besseren Zugang zur Sprache zu ermöglichen.

Comment: So wie ich es verstanden habe, erstand die Vorsilbe "ge-"  im Mittelhochdeutschen um eine Veränderung eines Zustands auszudrücken.  Wenn man sich freut verändert sich der Zustand ja von nicht-Freude zu Freude. Vielleicht könnte es eine Reste davon sein?

Comment: Ich schließe mich der Theorie von @Beta an. Es gibt ja eine Reihe von Verben, die genau das umgekehrte Verhalten zeigen und im Perfekt ohne "ge-" stehen müssen: "i hob trogn, i bin kemma(n)". Vermutlich ein Erbe der Zeit, in der "ge-" ein Derivativ mit Aspektbedeutung war.

Comment: Man vergleiche auch Wörter wie *gleich, glauben*, schweizerisch (?) *gespüren, gereuen* oder schweizerdeutsch *gseh, ghöre* im Gegensatz zu *luege, lose* u.v.a.m.

Comment: Übrigens ist *gefreut* als Adjektiv durchaus Hochdeutsch, und Schweizer Hochdeutsch, vgl. [Blogwiese » die gefreute Sache](http://www.blogwiese.ch/archives/450) oder [gefreut – DWB](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?lemma=gefreut) oder einfach ["gefreute sache" - Google-Suche](https://www.google.com/search?q="gefreute+sache").

Comment: @mach Hmm, bei *gefreut* als Adjektiv wäre ich vorsichtig; das kann auch schlichtweg das Partizip II von *freuen* sein …

Comment: Es gibt evtl. eine Verbindung zu "gefallen"...

Comment: Das Thema ansich ist seltsam und mir erschliesst sich der Sinn der Frage immer noch nicht ganz. Was ich aber anmerken kann ist: [http://www.bayrisches-woerterbuch.de/gfrein-gfreuen-frein-freuen-sich/](http://www.bayrisches-woerterbuch.de/gfrein-gfreuen-frein-freuen-sich/)   und [http://www.bayrisches-woerterbuch.de/gstellen-sich/](http://www.bayrisches-woerterbuch.de/gstellen-sich/)

Answer (score 1):

Diese For
men sind Infinitive mit ge-, die im Frühneuhochdeutschen vor Allem in Verbindung mit dem Verb "mögen" auftraten. Andere, im modernen Standarddeutsch vorhandene Beispiele von Infinitiven mit ge- sind

- gelingen
- gehören
- genießen
- gewinnen

s. [Peter Gallmann: *Infinite Verbformen*](http://www.personal.uni-jena.de/~x1gape/Wort/Wort_Verb_infinit.pdf), S. 6

Comment: Servus. Danke für die kurze Antwort, die ich erst jetzt sehen konnte, da ich lange nicht mehr eingeloggt war. Ist es möglich, noch ein bisschen tiefer zu gehen? Was unterscheidet Infinitive mit *ge* von denjenigen ohne *ge?* *Hören* hat für meine Ohren (Kalauer bewusst eingesetzt) keine Verbindung zu *gehören;* ist die etymologisch systematisch verloren gegangen? Bisher ist die Antwort in meinen Augen lediglich ein Fragment, was mich leider davon abhält, sie mit +1 zu bewerten.

Comment: @Jan Ich denke, eine Antwort, die alle Infinitive mit ge- abdeckt, ist schwerlich zu finden. Ich meine damit: Es gibt wohl keinen (leicht zu beschreibenden) Bedeutungskern des Präfix. Was Deine konkrete Frage zu 'gehören' angeht, siehe https://www.dwds.de/wb/geh%C3%B6ren#et-1